# Detect if CGPoint within polygon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I have a set of CGPoints which make up a polygon shape, how can I detect if a single CGPoint is inside or outside of the polygon?

Say, the shape was a triangle and the CGPoint was moving hoizontally, how could I detect when it crossed the triangle line?

I can use `CGRectContainsPoint` when the shape is a regular 4-sided shape but I can't see how I would do it with an odd shape.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can create a `CG(Mutable)PathRef` (or a `UIBezierPath` that wraps a `CGPathRef`) from your points and use the [`CGPathContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathContainsPoint) function to check if a point is inside that path. If you use `UIBezierPath`, you could also use the `containsPoint:` method.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to write one method that implements a point inside polygon algorithm.

This method will take an array with N points (the polygon) as an argument and one specific point. It should return true if the point is inside the polygon and false if not.

[See this great answer on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation in Swift:

```
extension CGPoint {
    
    func isInsidePolygon(vertices: [CGPoint]) -> Bool {
        guard vertices.count > 0 else { return false }
        var i = 0, j = vertices.count - 1, c = false, vi: CGPoint, vj: CGPoint
        while true {
            guard i < vertices.count else { break }
            vi = vertices[i]
            vj = vertices[j]
            if (vi.y > y) != (vj.y > y) &&
                x < (vj.x - vi.x) * (y - vi.y) / (vj.y - vi.y) + vi.x {
                c = !c
            }
            j = i
            i += 1
        }
        return c
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Swift 3**

A simpler way using Swift 3, is using `UIBezierPath` `contains` method.

When creating an instance of `CAShapeLayer`, make sure to set the `accessibilityPath`

```
shapeLayer.path = bazierPath.cgPath
shapeLayer.accessibilityPath = bazierPath
```

Checking if path contains touch location.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }

    for shape in layer.sublayers ?? [] where shape is CAShapeLayer {
        guard let layer = shape as? CAShapeLayer,
            let bazier = layer.accessibilityPath else { continue }

        // Handle touch
        print(bazier.contains(point))
    }
}
```