# Check if a set of coordinates are contained within a shape

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if CGPoint within polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952476/detect-if-cgpoint-within-polygon)

I have the coordinates of a set of touches from a `UIEvent`. Is there a way to check if they are contained within a certain shape -- a polygon -- that I can define?

I have experience in Java, and I would use the `polygon` class and call the `contains(int x, int y)` method. Is there a similar way to do this in Cocoa Touch?

Answer (score 3):

If you define your polygon as a `CGPath`, you can use `CGPathContainsPoint()`... Can you tell us more about your application concept?

EDIT:

There's also the higher-level `UIBezierPath` and/or `NSBezierPath`.. both of those objects have a `-containsPoint` method.

Comment: Thanks. That seems exactly what I'm looking for. I couldn't find this solution for the life of me.

Comment: well, this is using the Core Graphics C API, so it's not at the level of Obj-C or C++... So it wouldn't appear in the Obj-C class documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, CGPoint point)`

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

OR

[Detect if CGPoint within polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952476/detect-if-cgpoint-within-polygon)

Comment: But the o.p. asked specifically about polygons...

Comment: ok, then I vote to close as a dupe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're doing something unusual, like you only want touches to be detected within a triangle or something. If so, you can ignore this. But since you're new to iOS, I would recommend using either a `UIControl` subclass with target-action pairs or a `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Example code would be:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Later in the `target` -- probably your view controller, you would implement the method:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
}
```

With a gesture recognizer, you would add the gesture recognizer to a `UIView` and, like with the `UIControl`, add a target-action pair:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
}
```

These are the typical approaches for basic user interaction. You'll have *much* simpler time with these than using `touchesBegan` & company, though if they are what you need then the other answerers have you covered.